# Confidence Interval with unknown distribution and n = 25

Tags: statistics

I'm given the sample mean of 8.2 and the population standard deviation of 0.72, and a random sample size of 25. I know that one can say that if n is equal or greater to 30, it approximates a normal distribution ... since 25 is close to 30, can I do this?

I don't know what my other option would be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For many purposes, $30$ is quite a conservative bound for this sort of thing.

If you have a highly skewed population distribution, then $30$ is nowhere near enough for the sample sum or sample average to be approximately normally distributed.
 For example, suppose $X = \left. \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 0.001, \\  0 & \text{with probability }0.999. \end{cases} \right\}$ Then the distribution of the sum of $30$ independent copies of $X$ is equal to $0$ with probability about $0.97$, equal to $1$ with probability about $0.029$ and greater than $1$ with probability less than $0.0005$.  Thus for this population, $30$ is nowhere near big enough.

**However,** for distributions that are not highly skewed, $12$ may be plenty.  For the uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$, a normal approximation to the distribution of the sum of just $8$ independent copies is not very bad.

So look at whether your distribution appears skewed.  If it's not, you're ok.